# Controlling decimal places displayed in a tibble. Understanding what pillar.sigfig does

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

I have a csv file `weight.csv` with the following contents.

```
weight,weight_selfreport
81.5,81.66969147005445
72.6,72.59528130671505
92.9,93.01270417422867
79.4,79.4010889292196
94.6,96.64246823956442
80.2,79.4010889292196
116.2,113.43012704174228
95.4,95.73502722323049
99.5,99.8185117967332
```

If I do

```
library(readr)
Df <- read_csv('weight.csv')
Df
```

I get

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  weight weight_selfreport
   <dbl>             <dbl>
1   81.5              81.7
2   72.6              72.6
3   92.9              93.0
4   79.4              79.4
5   94.6              96.6
6   80.2              79.4
7  116.              113. 
8   95.4              95.7
9   99.5              99.8
```

If I convert that tibble to a normal data frame, I'll see more digits.

```
as.data.frame(Df)
  weight weight_selfreport
1   81.5          81.66969
2   72.6          72.59528
3   92.9          93.01270
4   79.4          79.40109
5   94.6          96.64247
6   80.2          79.40109
7  116.2         113.43013
8   95.4          95.73503
9   99.5          99.81851
```

Initially I thought that if I wanted to get this type of display for the tibble, I thought I would do `options(pillar.sigfig = 5)`.

However, that's not what it does.

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 5)
Df
# A tibble: 9 x 2
   weight weight_selfreport
    <dbl>             <dbl>
1  81.5              81.670
2  72.600            72.595
3  92.9              93.013
4  79.4              79.401
5  94.6              96.642
6  80.2              79.401
7 116.2             113.43 
8  95.4              95.735
9  99.5              99.819
```

And so I see that `pillar.sigfig` is about controlling significant digits not decimals places.

Fine but

- Why is (row 2, col 1) 72.6 being displayed as 72.600?
- What can I do, or can I do anything, to get five decimals places?

Comment: Hi, to answer the second question: you can set `options(pillar.sigfig = 7)`.
The first question is very interesting.
Also consider this example: `options(pillar.sigfig = 4)` 
`tibble(a = 60.1, b = 70.1)`

`options(pillar.sigfig = 5)`
`tibble(a = 60.1, b = 70.1)`

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to reformulate the question with smaller test data.

Answer (score 5):

This might come a little late...3 years late, but it might help others looking for answers.

The issue lies with `tibble`. It has a very opinionated way of representing dfs. I presume, you often do not feel the need to look at your data in this way, but if you do, there are two options I frequently use that potentially are just another workaround.

**Option 1: Use `num()`**

This neat function enforces decimals. So you can `mutate()` all columns you want to format with the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
~ weight, ~ weight_selfreport,
81.5,81.66969147005445,
72.6,72.59528130671505,
92.9,93.01270417422867,
79.4,79.4010889292196,
94.6,96.64246823956442,
80.2,79.4010889292196,
116.2,113.43012704174228,
95.4,95.73502722323049,
99.5,99.8185117967332
)

data <-
  data %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ num(., digits = 3)))

data
#> # A tibble: 9 × 2
#>      weight weight_selfreport
#>   <num:.3!>         <num:.3!>
#> 1    81.500            81.670
#> 2    72.600            72.595
#> 3    92.900            93.013
#> 4    79.400            79.401
#> 5    94.600            96.642
#> 6    80.200            79.401
#> 7   116.200           113.430
#> 8    95.400            95.735
#> 9    99.500            99.819
```

**Option 2: Use table packages**

Usually, when I inspect a `tibble` it is because it contains results I want to report. Thus, I use one of the many table-generator packages, e.g.

- `flextable`,
- `gt`,
- `formattable`,
- `reactable`,
- etc.

Here is an example you can try using `flextable`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  
~ weight, ~ weight_selfreport,
81.5,81.66969147005445,
72.6,72.59528130671505,
92.9,93.01270417422867,
79.4,79.4010889292196,
94.6,96.64246823956442,
80.2,79.4010889292196,
116.2,113.43012704174228,
95.4,95.73502722323049,
99.5,99.8185117967332
)

flextable::flextable(data)
```

I assume **Option 1** might have been what you were looking for.

Comment: I get `could not find function "num"`.  What package is `num` from please?

Comment: Nvm, found it.  It is `tibble::num`.  (Funny how you can use tibbles, e.g. with `dplyr`, without loading the `tibble` library)

Comment: `library(tidyverse)` launches the core packages of the tidyverse, including the `tibble` package. Thus, I was able to use it without using `tibble::num()`.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  I never load the `tidyverse`, only individual libraries so I know exactly where functions/data are coming from and avoid unexpected behaviour without having to use namespaces everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. Using pillar.sigfig helps. You can also use it with round() and you have more control. But if the last figure is 0 it will not display it.

The "trick" I used was to save the results in a variable and then use print.data.frame(). Then it works fine. But maybe there is an easier solution...